# Not able to edit list view

Tags: configuration

I have system admin profile, But still i am not able to edit list view it is showing following error:

> This View Unique Name already exists or has been previously used. Please choose a different name

I checked profile level permission also, all are set.

Comment: Are you changing the name? Sounds like you're trying to set it to a value that is already taken.

Comment: No, i am trying to change only filter criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be someone has created a List View with **same API name** and made that **visible to that user**.

Thats why, as a system admin you can't see the other view which has the same API name.

So, you can edit your view and give different API name and click on `Save As` button and it will work.

Comment: Save as is working, but then i have to give different queue name, i want to edit same view.Since it is share with different types of clients.

Comment: just mistyped, i mean different view name

Comment: You should create different view names with unique APIs and you can specify who are the users can see this view

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with the UI

- When you edit a list view and change the API Name, and click Save, you are replacing the listview
- When you edit a ListView and click Save As without changing the API name, you are trying to save a new instance of the ListView that matches some other list view by API name - most likely the List View you started the editing on before you clicked Save As

This problem is exacerbated by the limited width of the API name in the UI lulling you into making mistakes